# How to access and change android device language settings programmatically?

Tags: android, settings

I am now developing an android application that can access android device language settings and change it to fit my needs, but I searched the web and tried but nothing can benefit me.

All I found is about changing the app language but not the whole device language.

Any idea?

I will be glad if you can help me :)

Answer (score 0):

For example, the command to switch the device language to German would be:

> adb shell "su -c 'setprop persist.sys.language de; setprop persist.sys.country de; stop; sleep 5; start'

You will need a rooted device in order for this to work